# Parse image PFFile :fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value!

Tags: swift, парсер, swift3, parse.com

Подскажите как в данном случае передать PFFile? не могу понять как это сделать, в моем проекте.Очень буду благодарен!!!
вот мой Код:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSportViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageDetail: UIImageView!


    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var titleDetail: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var prognozDetail: UILabel!

    var soccers : Soccer?
    var baskets : Basketball?
    var tenises : Tennis?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()






        textView.font = textView.font?.withSize(10)
        detailObject()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            }


    @IBOutlet weak var outClose: UIButton! {

        didSet {
            outClose.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            outClose.layer.masksToBounds = true



        }
    }



    @IBAction func actionClose(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    }


        func detailObject() {

             let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageDetail.image!, 0.5)
            let file = PFFile(name: "imageDetail.jpg", data: imageData!)

       let detailView = PFObject(className: "soccer")
       detailView["detailImageS"] = file
       detailView["detailTitles"] = "Манчестер Сити - Шахтер"
       detailView["detailTextS"] = "После потери Срны в распоряжении главного тренера «Шахтера» Пауло Фонсеки остался лишь один правый защитник – основной футболист сборной Украины Богдан Бутко."
      detailView["detailPrognozS"] = "прогноз на матч: тотал больше 10 угловых."
    detailView.saveInBackground {(success, error) -> Void in
                if(success){
                    print("Saved successful")

                } else {
                    print(error!)

                }

            }

    let detailInformation = Soccer()
    detailInformation.detailTextS = textView.text!
    detailInformation.detailPrognozS = prognozDetail.text!
    detailInformation.detailTitleS = titleDetail.text!
            detailInformation.detailImageS = file!
    detailInformation.detailImageS.getDataInBackground() { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = data {
                        self.imageDetail.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }


       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка скорее всего тут:

```
func detailObject() {

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageDetail.image!, 0.5)
    let file = PFFile(name: "imageDetail.jpg", data: imageData!)
..........
```

---

Можно вот так проверить:

```
func detailObject() {
    var imageData: Data? = nil

    if (imageDetail.image != nil) {
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageDetail.image!, 0.5)
    } else {
        print("image in imageView is nil")
        return
    }
    var file: PFFile? = nil
    if (imageData != nil) {
        file = PFFile(name: "imageDetail.jpg", data: imageData!)
    } else {
        print("image data is nil")
        return
    }
..........
```

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей.пробую.Слушай я тебе на почту написал, ты письмо получил? вот моя почта a.ilyin007@gmail.com

Comment: да, получил, не за что

Comment: да, идет.Только не могу понять почему не загружаются данные с сервера.

Comment: что в командную строку выдает ? не идет потому что я return вставил если какие-то из данных nil

Comment: Знаешь ошибок, ни как нет.Я тебе на почту скину.Что как у меня идет проект, а ты что не правильно сделал.